# NHibernate ICriteria - Does the sort allow for null?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, .net-3.5

Using NHibernate ICriteria and adding .AddOrder ... I want to sort by a property that is sometimes null with all the populated ones at the top. Will .AddOrder allow me to do this? If not is there an alternative?

The sorting options for ILists leave a lot to be desired.

Comment: In .NET 3.5 there are some extension methods for IList<T> that bring it on par with List<T>.  I think it's a project on codeplex... look around for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get the non-null values first by using that method. We use sorting in that way on my project, and have not had any issues with the null values... they get listed at end.

Answer (score 5):

If you use something similar to:

```
IList cats = sess.CreateCriteria(typeof(Cat))
    .AddOrder( Order.Desc("PropertyName") )
    .List();
```

The objects with NULLs for the given property will be last in the list.

*(Taken in part from the [NHibernate documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria).)*

Comment: I realize it's been awhile but that link doesn't work.  http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria should do it.

Comment: What if you sort by `.AddOrder( Order.Desc("NullableProperty.GrandchildProperty"))`? Can you still get all the parent objects, even with `null` for `NullableProperty`?